# Virtual env Python packages with Google Cloud SDK

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, virtualenv, google-cloud-sdk

I'm in the Getting Started section of Google Cloud SDK from Dan Sanderson's book, sorry no link.

The thing is I created a clock application with the local installation of Python. 
Then I created a virtual environment, and ran the same application with the corresponding installation.
I installed the packages that I needed, but I get a strange error about -what I think- is one of the base Python packages.

```
(myenv) diego@host:gae-clock$ dev_appserver.py .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 11, in <module>
    import bootstrapping.bootstrapping as bootstrapping
  File ".../google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", 
    line 9, in <module>
    import setup
ImportError: No module named 'setup'
```

thank you for pointing in the right direction.  Please let me know if I can show more to track this down.

Comment: Seems your virtualenv is missing setuptools. `pip install setuptools`?

Comment: Thanks for the message, I got `Requirement already satisfied` and even upgraded it, but it's still not running.

Comment: Can you please take a look at what I wrote here: https://www.jeffgodwyll.com/posts/2015/google-appegine-vendoring-done-right/ ? If it helps, I could craft an answer out of it :)

Comment: This is a useful post, that I will put into practice for my development.  The bad news it didn't help with my issue.  The good news is I found out what the problem was.  That is, virtualenv is tied to Python3 even when run without options, and from what I understand App Engine runs on Python2.  Cheers.

Comment: Cool. Glad you resolved this.

Comment: I just confirmed my venv runs python 2, but Im having the same stupid issue.... is there a way to hack the venv's pythonpath? or just install the sdk modules mannualy?

Comment: Jeff, looks like your tutorial could be really helpful, but im kinda dumb. when you say "Symlink the virtualenv's site packages to the lib folder" what lib folder are you referencing?